# No showing ads in videos in desktop

Tags: video.js, vast

This is my html Code: the video is playing but no ads are shown. Please tell me what is wrong with this code. I got this code from videojs website for streaming my videos. I am not experienced in Javascript. Please support. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Video.js VAST Example</title>
        <link href="videojs/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="vast/lib/videojs-contrib-ads/videojs.ads.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="vast/videojs.vast.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">
            .description {
                background-color:#eee;
                border: 1px solid #777;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: .8em;
                line-height: 1.5em;
                font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            .example-video-container {
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="lib/es5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="videojs/video.js"></script>
        <script src="vast/lib/videojs-contrib-ads/videojs.ads.js"></script>
        <script src="vast/lib/vast-client.js"></script>
        <script src="vast/videojs.vast.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="description">Video.js VAST plugin examples.</p>
        <div class="example-video-container">
            <p class="description">With autoplay.</p>
            <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay controls preload="auto"
                   poster="images/nisshabdam.jpg"
                   data-setup='{}'
                   width='640'
                   height='400'
                   >
                <source src="myfilm.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" /> 
                <p>Video Playback Not Supported</p>
            </video>
        </div>
        <script>
            var vid1 = videojs('vid1');
            vid1.muted(true);
            vid1.ads(),
                    vid1.vast({
                        url: 'https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=1760'
                    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I go to your VAST URL:

https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=1760

...I get a 403 HTTP error. That's probably the reason. You can ask your video ad network to get a working tag. Note that not all advertisers may want to advertise on your website, so you may not get an ad on every page view.